# Pivot a dataframe with two columns as the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have data in the following format:

```
Record ID Para Tag
1          A    x
1          A    y
2          B    x 
2          B    y
1          A    z
```

I want to transform the data into the following format:

```
Record Para x_Tag y_Tag z_Tag
1       A    1     1      1
2       B    1     1      0
```

Need some guidance to do so in Pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['RecordID','Para'])).sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index()
Out[132]: 
   RecordID Para  Tag_x  Tag_y  Tag_z
0         1    A      1      1      1
1         2    B      1      1      0
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what `sum(level=[0,1])` does?

Comment: @kurious sum base on index , cause we setting those two columns as index , can we want to combine all the row have the same index to one row after get_dummies

Comment: @kurious How big is your dataFrame?

Comment: 18720 rows × 3 columns -> before applying the solutions
5776 rows × 449 columns -> after applying the solution

Answer (score 2):

#### `pivot_table`

`pivot_table` works nicely here, and should be fast:

```
df.pivot_table(
    index=['Record ID', 'Para'], columns='Tag', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0
).add_prefix('Tag_').reset_index()

Tag  Record ID Para  Tag_x  Tag_y  Tag_z
0            1    A      1      1      1
1            2    B      1      1      0
```

---

#### `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(
    [df['Record ID'], df['Para']], df['Tag']
).add_prefix('Tag_').reset_index()

Tag  Record ID Para  Tag_x  Tag_y  Tag_z
0            1    A      1      1      1
1            2    B      1      1      0
```